# Creating and running multiple Java windows using one class

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, actionlistener

Below program will create 2 simple windows where we can type some text, and it will be shown in both windows' display screen.

I created a Class to generate UI. However, when I use the same class to create 2 objects (typeWriterObj1 & typeWriterObj2) and click on btnSend.

The typed in message are always directed and displayed in the last created window (For example: I type text into Alice's `txtMessage` and click `btnSend`, text is shown in Bob's window instead of Alice's).

**See below example:**

```
public class TextProgram
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        TypeWriterUI typeWriterObj1 = new TypeWriterUI();    
        TypeWriterUI typeWriterObj2 = new TypeWriterUI();                    
        TypeWriterObj1.showGUI("Alice");            
        TypeWriterObj2.showGUI("Bob");          
    }    
}

class TypeWriterUI extends JPanel
{
    static JButton btnSend;
    static JTextArea txtDisplay = new JTextArea();
    static JTextArea txtMessage = new JTextArea();

        //...Codes which add the swing components

        //ActionListerner for btnSend which transfer input text from txtMessage to txtDisplay
}
```

**Que:** How can this problem be resolved if I were not to use multi-threading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undo making the fields `static` (one instance per class). Both GUIs shared every button instance. That this worked is even a miracle; probably twice assigned a new JButton to the same variable and so on.

Comment: Thanks for that. But if I want the text typed in from one window to show in both windows, can I use static for that? I will remove static for the button anyway. :)

Comment: No, any GUI component, like JTextField, holds a reference to its parent, and that can only be one. You can add a change listener, and pass the new value to a controller object holding both GUI classes, and passing that new value to the other class. This is the so-called MVC, Model-Vieew-Controller, pattern. Best hold the JFrames and provide them with `public void updateText(String newValue);`.